# How to set command timeout for individual queries in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I know the command timeout can be set using the `context.Database.SetCommandTimeout` method. But this changes the timeout for all the queries that are made using the same `DbContext` instance.

I know I can set the timeout, run the query and reset the timeout, but this feels like a hack. I want to set the timeout per query. Similar to how `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` can be set in ADO.NET for each query. Is it possible to do that with EF Core?

Comment: I don't see a very big difference between setting the timeout "inside" the function call `Execute(timeout, sql)` and setting it one line before. "hiding" sql commands (you often only have linq queries) has a cost cleary: you can't explicitly control many small details, and if you want to control them you must return to using explicit methods.

Comment: If you need a longer timeout for one of the queries, why not set it longer per context instance anyway? If the other queries don't need it, they won't notice.

Comment: Yep.  If having the same timeout for all queries called for a single DbContext instance is a problem, you probably are keeping the DbContext instance alive too long.

Comment: I see it valid to have fast queries and long-running queries. Having a short timeout allows you to handle what you expect from most of your queries and thus give a quick response in case of a timeout. On queries that you know will take longer to run (exceptions rather than the rule), you'd want to assign them a higher timeout threshold without generalizing to all your other queries.

Comment: @GertArnold because then you lose one of the key benefits of timeouts - knowing when your query is slow (for whatever reason). Depends entirely on what you're building of course, but users will often tolerate long timeouts and without errors you may never know about it. Of course it's tricky to find a balance - especially if a 29 second query starts taking 31 seconds right when you head off on vacation :-)

Comment: Reminder: `SetCommandTimeout` is an extension method, so make sure to add **using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in my comment, it isn't something I think is necessary or really really useful. I've debugged a little the code of EF Core (it is quite easy with VS 2019, by letting it load the symbols from the nuget server or by forcing it to decompile to source code). There are some "insertion points" we could call where you could inject something to modify the `SetCommandTimeout` for a single query. For example for LINQ queries a

```
public class MyCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }
}
```

with an

```
.AddInterceptors(new MyCommandInterceptor());
```

put where you configure your `DBContext` is probably the best place. When the interceptor is run the `DbCommand command` has already the standard `Timeout` set and you can change it. The problem cleary is setting the timeout you want and passing this information to the interceptor. This is complex and I'm not sure that there are good solutions (I think there are various ugly solutions... It seems to be difficult to add informations during query building and letting the interceptor know about this information)

If you are interested, the `DbCommand` is created in [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.CreateDbCommand()`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/da00fb69d615fa22a83dfee2077ad31b7bd15823/src/EFCore.Relational/Storage/RelationalCommand.cs#L606).

If you want something pre-packaged the response is no, there is nothing. You are clearly free to suggest it as feature in the [efcore github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues). If modifying the source code of EF it would be relatively easy to add this feature.